# Modular Program

Tags: c, module

I am brand new to programming, and I have to create a modular C program which allows a user to enter a positive, even number between 1 and 23, and only accepts those values. It must also maintain a running sum of the numbers, continue asking for numbers as long as the sum is less than 98. It must also keep track of the largest and smallest number entered, display the sum and min and max value, and must allow new numbers to be entered.

I have attached my program down below. I do not know how to get the sum of the numbers to work or how to produce the minimum and maximum value. I have been trying to use `sum += i` to find the sum, and I have been trying to use a variable compared to the integer entered to find the minimum and max, however I cannot get it to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    inputNumber();
    sumNumber();
    smallVsLarge();
    moreInput();
}

inputNumber()
{
    int i = 0;

     while (i <= 22)
     { 
         printf("\nPlease enter an even number between 1 and 23: ");
         scanf ("%d", &i);

         if (i%2==1)
         {
             printf ("Please enter another number: ");
             scanf ("%d", &i);
         }
         else if ( i < 0)
         {
             printf("Please enter another number: ");
             scanf ("%d", &i);
         }
         else if (i > 23)
         {
             printf("Please enter another number: ");
             scanf ("%d", &i);
         }

         sumNumber(i);
    }
}

sumNumber(int i)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int n;

    for (n = 1; n <= i; n++)
    {
        sum = sum + n;

        if (sum >= 98)
        {
            moreInput();
        }
    }

    printf ("Your running total is %d.\n", sum);
    smallVsLarge(i);
}

smallVsLarge(int i)
{
    int min, max;
    max = 0;
    min = 22;

    for (i = 0 ; i <= 22; i++)
    {
        if (i < min)
        {
            min = i;
        }
        else if (i > max)
        {
            max = i;
        }
    }

    printf ("Your smallest value is %d and your largest value is %d.\n", min, max);
}


moreInput(int sum)
{
    int x;

    while (sum > 98)
    {
        printf("\n\nYou have reached the maximum sum. Enter 0 to Quit or 1 to Start Over: ");
        scanf("%d",&x);

        if(x==0)
        {
            break;
        }
        else if (x==1)
        {
            inputNumber();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code so it's readable.

Comment: Reminds me of some steepest steps in stair cases.

Answer (score 0):

The `stuff` you have created in functions(callee) will be freed when it returns to where it is called except what you explicitly return to the caller.

Also ANSI C(C90 if I recall correctly) has introduced function declaration. For example, if you plan to have a function sum which will take one argument and return the sum, you could write a prototype for it in the beginning of the program like below

```
int sum(int); 
/* This just says the function sum will take an argument of type integer and
 * it returns an integer.
 */
```

If you do this in the beginning, at the point where you define the function, you will have a clear idea how to define it in terms of the number of arguments it take and what it **SHOULD** return.